# Accessing Font thrown License Restrictions Exception

Tags: c#, fonts

I have a code where it enumerates all the system fonts into dropdownlist. When accessing that font I am getting `License Restrictions` exception.

My question here is that, How to avoid adding those unavailable fonts into dropdownlist.

**My Code**

```
 foreach (FontFamily font in System.Drawing.FontFamily.Families.Where(ds=>ds.IsStyleAvailable(ds.Name)))
 {
     ddllblFontFamilyHead.Items.Add(font.Name); ddllblFontFamilyItemNo.Items.Add(font.Name);
 }
```

Comment: Does it error on the line of adding font.name to the lists or later?

Comment: No. The problem is happening only when I access the font not when adding to the list. I was accessing from one of the pdf generator.

Comment: Only way you could avoid adding barfy fonts then would be to try using the font before adding it, if it barfs, skip it